# Evaluate ${M\over2R^2}\int(R^2 - y^2)^{3\over2}dy$

Tags: integration

I was finding the moment of inertia of a hollow sphere, and got stuck on the integration of:
$${M\over2R^2}\int(R^2 - y^2)^{3\over2}dy$$

Any hint to as to solve this integral? Please help.

Substituting $t = R^2 - y^2$
$${M\over2R^2}\int(R^2 - y^2)^{3\over2}dy = {M\over2R^2}\int(t)^{3\over2}dy$$
$$={M\over2R^2}{2\over5}t^{5\over2}$$
$$={M\over(R^2)}{1\over5}t^{5\over2}$$

Will I get the integral upon substituting value of $t$?

Moment of Inertia:
Considering the hollow sphere to be made of small rings, of thickness dy, radius x and of mass dm:
$$dI = dm(x)^2$$
$$dm = {Mxdy\over2R^2}$$

Upon drawing a figure:
$$x^2 = R^2 - y^2$$
$$dI = {Mxdy\over2R^2}(x)^2$$
$$I = {M\over2R^2}\int(x^3)dy$$
$$I = {M\over2R^2}\int(R^2 - y^2)^{3\over2}dy$$

---

Let p be the areal mass density
$$p = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}$$
$$dm = p * 2\pi R dy$$
$$dm = {Mxdy\over2R^2}$$

Comment: Substitute $y = R \sin t$. That'll get you an integral of something like $\cos^4 t$; for that, use the half-angle formula, twice.

Comment: At a guess: Substitute in $t=R^2-y^2$?

Comment: This is a standard result. First substitution $y = R\sin t$. You then end up with an integral of $\cos^4$. You can then use $\cos(2t) = 1 - 2\cos^2(t)$ twice to reduce the power of trig functions down to something straightforward.

Comment: Either go into spherical coordinates (obvious choice for a sphere) or do integration by parts (integrate y, differentiate the rest).

Comment: @columbus8myhw That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @orion Not sure if I understand what you mean. I just have to solve the integral?

Comment: @John Ummm.... Lost you. How exactly does that help me solve this integral?

Comment: Why not do the substitution and tell us what you got exactly? Then we can maybe help you along. Four different people have done just what you asked -- "Any hint?" -- by giving you hints. It's unlikely that we're all wrong. So why not show us what you get when you pursue our suggestions? By the way, you might want to specify the limits of integration as well -- you'll need them later in the process.

Comment: @John I edited the question.

Comment: Moment of inertia calculation should not have a fractional exponent. Can you show more of how you arrived at this.

Comment: @ja72 Sure I'll edit the question.

Comment: Your substitution didn't include $dt = -2y ~dy$, which is a problem (and a reason why this particular substitution might not be the best one).  Perhaps you need to review integration-by-substitution.  In the meantime, look at Simon's answer to see what he and I were talking about.

Comment: @John But won't the substitution method only work if the integral was of $(R^2-y^2)^{3\over2}2y$?

Comment: I think your $dm$ is suspeect. If you do $\int dm = \int \frac{M \sqrt{R^2-y^2}}{2 R^2}\,{\rm d}y = \frac{\pi}{8} M R \ne M$. Shouldn't by definition $M=\int dm$?

Comment: Nope: you can take $R^2 - y^2 = t$ and solve for $y$ to get $y = \sqrt{R^2 - t}$; then $dt - -2y~dy$ becomes $\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{R^2 - t}} dt = dy$. When you perform that substitution, you get something that's just as bad as what you started with, but the substitution works fine. That's why Simon and I suggested the sine substitution -- it works better.

Comment: @ja72 I edited question. Please check again.

Comment: BTW, ja72's comment looks right to me: the sphere's surface isn't made of little rings; it's made of little frusta of cones. The differential area, at height $y$, is about $1/\sqrt{1 - y^2}$ times the area you've estimated. Whether this makes a difference in computing moment of inertia isn't obvious to me, but it certainly makes a difference in computing the surface area of the sphere.

Comment: Dimensionally you integral is incorrect. The result should be of the mass times distance squared units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my hint explicit, with $y = R\sin t$, $dy = R\cos t \ dt$ and the integral equals

$$\frac{M}{R^2}\int (R^2(1-\sin^2 t))^{3/2} . R\cos t \ dt = MR^2 \int \cos^4 t \ dt$$

Now $\cos^2 t = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2t))$, one of the 'half-angle' relations of trig. Hence $$\cos^4 t = \left( \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(2t)) \right)^2 = \frac{1}{4} \left( 1 + 2\cos(2t) + \cos^2(2t)\right)$$ Integrating the first two of those terms is straightforward. Use the 'half-angle' formula for $\cos^2$ again to integrate the last term.

Answer (score 0):

If you slice your hollow sphere with horizontal slices of ${\rm d}y$ thickness the mass of the sphere is

$$ M = \int \limits_0^R w {\rm d}y $$ where $w$ is some kind of linear mass density, found to be $w=\frac{M}{R}$

The mass moment of inertia is similarly equal to

$$ I = \int \limits_0^R w x^2 {\rm d}y = \int \limits_0^R \frac{M}{R} \sqrt{R^2-y^2} {\rm d}y$$

The above evaluates to $I=\frac{2}{3} M R^2$ which is the correct answer according to http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/isph.html

I used $(x,y)=(R \cos \theta,R \sin \theta)$ substitution in the integral to make it super easy.

Comment: I see. But won't you use areal mass density rather than linear?

Comment: If real mass density $\rho$ is used then $w = \int \rho {\rm d}x$ Now the limits of this integration depend on $y$. To do this right your slicing has to be done with a polar angle ${\rm d}\theta$ instead of ${\rm d}y$. Then $dm = \rho \pi x^2  R d \theta d R$ instead of $dm=\rho \pi x^2 dx dy$

Comment: The difficulty is the for a thin shell $\int dx = 0$, but $\int \rho dx >0$. Real mass density is infinite since the material volume of a hollow sphere is zero.